# Month/Date Selection question - What's wrong with this?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I'm having a hard time understanding what is wrong with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358050/selecting-an-appropriate-design-for-month-date-selection) I asked. I'd like to hear what this question is lacking and how to make it better (or know if it isn't salvageable).

- Is my question unclear? Perhaps it was unclear in the beginning but I tried to elaborate as much as possible, including details in comments as well.
- Is the question not fit for StackOverflow? If not, where should I have posted it?
- Is the answer to the question so obvious that I should not be asking here? I tried lots of google searches but I couldn't find any relevant information.
- Am I asking too many things in a single question? If I separate the questions, I lose context and I feared people would be even more confused.

So yeah, I'm thinking real hard where I went wrong but really I can't think of anything :( Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, it's a design question, which isn't usually something that is on-topic here. There can be a fine line there sometimes, especially if a 'design' question gets into detail about specific code. Ultimately, that's the issue; the question isn't about specific code.

To your points:

- Your question seems clear, for what it is.
- The topic of software design tends to be more on topic on Programmers, **but** I am not remotely qualified to say if that question would be appropriate there, otherwise. <sup>1</sup>
- There's no problem with 'obviousness' here, IMO.
- Design questions do tend to be a little bit more broad by nature.

You have gotten some halfway decent comments about it<strike>, but yes; you might consider removing the question. If you think you can edit it into a specific code question, that might be worthwhile, too.</strike>

<sup>1</sup> As noted in the comments below, a Programmer's moderator migrated your question [to Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209023/selecting-an-appropriate-design-for-month-date-selection)

Comment: Well I understand what you are saying but I'm still having a hard time accepting this. I've seen plenty of design question on this site which were answered well by experts. I could always add some code to my initial design approach, but that doesn't change the nature of the question I'm asking - I'm just giving the readers an illusion that I have some code to show to make the question seem more fit to SO. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: Also, assuming it is fit for Programmers, how do I request the question to be moved?

Comment: @l46kok I know what you mean. Because of Stack Overflow's relative popularity, and the awesome answering-powers of some of the experts we have here, there are many "design" questions that do get good answers here. It can be hit-or-miss at times.

Comment: @l46kok I'm going to see if there's a Programmer's mod around to see if that's a question they would like there. One sec...

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! Really appreciate the hard work mods do here

Comment: @l46kok The question was migrated by a Programmer's mod. Good luck, and kudos for a *very* constructive question here asking about it.

Comment: s/Programmer's mod/Stack Overflow mod/everywhere mod